# What happens if I call subprocess using gevent?

Tags: python, asynchronous, subprocess, gevent

I'm putting together some code that's meant to glue a bunch of legacy code together. Part of this involves me invoking python from within my code, using the `subprocess` module.
If I was running this code from the command line, I'd run groups of these commands at once in the background. What I'd like to do is replicate that behaviour.
The most obvious way to me seems to be to use `gevent`, but if it was that easy, wouldn't this be a common and easy workaround for the GIL?
So, what is `subprocess` doing at a low level? Is it running in a different thread to my Python process?
In my head I want to do something like this.

```
import subprocess

import gevent.monkey
from gevent.pool import Pool

gevent.monkey.patch_all()


def run_one(command):
    rc = subprocess.check_call(command)
    return rc  


def run_async(commands):
    pool = Pool(5)
    pool.map(run_one, commands)
```

Comment: not a different thread, but a different process. That's why it is call sub*process*.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Why isn't this used more often to get around the GIL then?

Comment: To get around the GIL use `multiprocessing`.